# React native expo unable to resolve .bin file

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow, expo, bin

I am trying to implement my tensorflow model into my react native expo file. The error i get is

`Android Bundling failed`

`Unable to resolve "./assets/group1-shard1of1.bin" from "App.js"`

Which is the correct path due to it finding the .json file that is also within that folder. I have tried to use the exact file path aswell but that does not resolve either.

Therefore i added a metro.config.js file with this code in it:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');
module.exports = (async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig();
  const { assetExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;
  return {
    resolver: {
      // Add bin to assetExts
      assetExts: [...assetExts, 'bin', 'json'],
    }
  };
})();
```

This does not solve my issue either. The code that the error comes from is:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function loadModel() {
      const tfReady = await tf.ready();
      const modelJSON = await require('./assets/model.json');
      const modelWeights = await require('./assets/group1-shard1of1.bin');
      const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights));

      setLicensePlateModel(model);
    }
    loadModel();
  }, []);
```

I think it is something wrong with how it handles .bin file but i am not sure